# Is the EXCEPTION in the wrong place? Where is the best place to put it?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So i am trying to create entries by looping through a cursor; however, I am trying to handle an exception (DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX) within the loop. IS this possible? IF so, what am I doing wrong? Below is my code:

```
create or replace Procedure EY IS
CURSOR c1 is 
  select ey_id , cycle_id
  from mvs v
 cross join cycle s
 l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN
      OPEN c1;
   LOOP
      BEGIN
        FETCH c1 into l_var;
        EXIT when c1%NOTFOUND;
      insert into EY (EY_id, cycle_id, create_dt, create_user_id)
      values (l_var.ey_id, l_var.cycle_id, trunc(sysdate), '1');
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('duplicate value');  
  END LOOP;
    close c1;
END EY;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `EXCEPTION` is not a command that you can throw just anywhere; it marks the end of the execution section and the start of the exception handling section of a PL/SQL block, which always has the structure `[DECLARE...] BEGIN... [EXCEPTION...] END;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the way to continue `LOOP` execution if something happens - enclose loop contents into its own `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block.

Your code seems to be OK, but it is missing the `END` statement for the mentioned inner `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-`**END** block, i.e.

```
create or replace Procedure EY IS
  CURSOR c1 is 
    select ey_id , cycle_id
    from mvs v
    cross join cycle s
  l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      FETCH c1 into l_var;
      EXIT when c1%NOTFOUND;
      insert into EY (EY_id, cycle_id, create_dt, create_user_id)
        values (l_var.ey_id, l_var.cycle_id, trunc(sysdate), '1');
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('duplicate value');  
    end;                   --> you're missing this END
  END LOOP;
  close c1;
END EY;
```

If you properly indent code, it is easier to spot the culprit.

Comment: thanks. yeah lesson learned, thanks for your help (as always) :)

Comment: Though if your write `BEGIN`, you should probably close it with `END`. (Or better still, `begin ... end`.)